# EF Core 6 command "add-migration" starts the app

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I've migrated from EF Core 5 to EF Core 6 in my ASP.NET Core app.

I have a separate console application which seeds database with data and stores migrations of `DbContext`.

I have made some changes in domain model and wanted to apply them with new migration.

As usually I've put in Package manager console command:

```
Add-Migration MуSql -context MigrationMySqlDbContext -OutputDir Migrations\MySql
```

But there's no new migration and in console I see messages which my console app writes when starting...

Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong?

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.2.0

Comment: [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) - It describes how the migration utility searches for and creates a context for its work. It needs either a host, or a constructor without parameters, or a design-time factory.

Comment: Thank you! I've created host as it was suggested in the doc-link, and it works